# Stackexchange top new users - month

Tags: support, reputation-leagues

```
Top New Users
[Rok Kralj]
Rok Kralj
523 ●10
joined: Sep 1, 2011

+453 reputation this month
```

1. I joined Sep 1
2. I have total 523 rep
3. I have 453 this month

Why do these numbers differ? Guess 70 difference came from other month?

Comment: Yes, it made me cofused because everywhere is a different number. Guess I am still getting used to things here. Thanks to everyone! And thanks for this *secret* link :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow and congratulations on a great start.  You hit the reputation cap twice in your first three days which is quite an accomplishment.

The Stack Exchange [top users](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow) pages, aka leagues, are recalculated only once per day.  That explains the difference between the reputation that the league reports for this month and the live number you see on the site itself.